# Escaping monad IO

Tags: haskell

One of the things I like best about Haskell is how the compiler locates the side effects via the IO monad in function signatures. However, it seems easy to bypass this type check by importing 2 GHC primitives :

```
{-# LANGUAGE MagicHash #-}

import GHC.Magic(runRW#)
import GHC.Types(IO(..))

hiddenPrint :: ()
hiddenPrint = case putStrLn "Hello !" of
  IO sideEffect -> case runRW# sideEffect of
    _ -> ()
```

`hiddenPrint` is of type unit, but it does trigger a side effect when called (it prints Hello). Is there a way to forbid those hidden IOs (other than trusting no one imports GHC's primitives) ?

Comment: I think the usefulness of IO (and similar safety features) should be measured in "how easy to make it work if you don't want to break it" not "how easy to break it if you want to break it".

Comment: Also, importing `System.IO.Unsafe` and using `unsafePerformIO` seems easier ;). It's easy to bypass, but _unsafe_.

Comment: `unsafeDupablePerformIO (IO m) = case runRW# m of (# _, a #) -> a` It's exactly the same, I didn't know this module though :) I stumbled upon `runRW#` when reading the simplifier's Core.

Comment: It's even more unsafe to use `realWorld#` instead of `runRW#`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the purpose of Safe Haskell. If you add `{-# language Safe #-}` to the top of your source file, you will only be allowed to import modules that are either inferred safe or labeled `{-# language Trustworthy #-}`. This also imposes some mild restrictions on overlapping instances.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways in which you can break purity in Haskell. However, you have to go out of your way to find them. Here are a few:

- Importing `GHC` internal modules to access low-level primitives
- Using the FFI to import a C function as a pure one, when it is not pure
- Using `unsafePerformIO`
- Using `unsafeCoerce`
- Using `Ptr a` and dereference pointers not pointing to valid data
- Declaring your own `Typeable` instances, and lying so that you can abuse `cast`. (No longer possible in recent GHC)
- Using the unsafe array operations

All these, and others, are not meant to be used regularly. They are there so that, if one is really, really sure, can tell the compiler "I know what I am doing, don't get in my way". Doing so, you take the burden of the proof -- proving that what you are doing is safe.

Comment: In recent GHC versions you can't define your own `Typeable` instances. The closest you could come would be to `unsafeCoerce` something like `Dict (Typeable a)`, but that would only have local effects.

Comment: @dfeuer I suspected this was no longer possible since automatic deriving was implemented. Thanks for the clarification.